# Splitting a string column with unequal size into multiple columns using R

Tags: r, string, split

There is a string column like this, in my data frame.

```
str=as.character(c("M 12; M 13","M 24", NA, "C 12; C 50; C 78"))
no=seq(1:4)
data.frame(no,str)

  no              str
1  1       M 12; M 13
2  2             M 24
3  3             <NA>
4  4 C 12; C 50; C 78
```

It has multiple values, separated by ";" symbol. I need to split this into multiple columns (3 columns based on this example) as each column contains only one value of the string. Will this be possible using R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good occasion to make use of `extra = merge` argument of `separate`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  separate(str, c('A', 'B', 'C'), sep= ";", extra = 'merge')
```

```
  no    A     B     C
1  1 M 12  M 13  <NA>
2  2 M 24  <NA>  <NA>
3  3 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
4  4 C 12  C 50  C 78
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_split`. Note, I assume you want to give the new columns a meaningful name, so I added a `rename_with`, but you can just cut it if you don't need:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(str = c("M 12; M 13","M 24", NA, "C 12; C 50; C 78"),
                 no = seq(1:4))

df %>%
  mutate(splits = str_split(str, "; ")) %>%
  unnest_wider(splits) %>%
  rename_with(.cols = starts_with("..."),
              .fn   = ~paste0("split_", 1:length(which(str_detect(., "...")))))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  str                 no split_1 split_2 split_3
  <chr>            <int> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 M 12; M 13           1 M 12    M 13    <NA>   
2 M 24                 2 M 24    <NA>    <NA>   
3 <NA>                 3 <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   
4 C 12; C 50; C 78     4 C 12    C 50    C 78
```